# Why won't my placeholder show up in TextInput

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I can't see why the placeholder won't show up on both of the `<TextInput>`'s.  Also, when the user types something, nothing shows up in those `<TextInput>` boxes.  I would like to know why this is happening.

Here is `App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import BackGround from './components/BackGround';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.back}>
                <BackGround/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    back: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Here is `Login.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={"Email"}
                    placeholderTextColor={"#E365F4"}
                    style={styles.input}
                />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder={"Password"}
                    placeholderTextColor={"#f44242"}
                    style={styles.input}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.loginAndCA}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.loginAndCA}>Create Account</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        paddingBottom: 20,
        padding: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 150,
        marginBottom: 10
    },

    loginAndCA: {
        fontSize: 40,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Bodoni 72 Smallcaps'
    }
});

export default Login;
```

Here is `BackGround.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image, View} from 'react-native';
import Login from './Login';

export default class BackGround extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.first}>
                <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../pictures/smoke.jpg')}>
                    <View style={styles.second}>
                        <Login/>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: null,
        height: null,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        resizeMode: 'cover'
        // resizeMode: 'contain' // Shows image completely.
    },

    first: {
        flex: 1
    },

    second: {
       paddingTop: 290 // Moves both <TextInput> boxes down.
    }

});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues here and it's all dealing with your styling.

1. By using `paddingBottom: 20` and `padding: 20`, you are effectively reducing what can be shown in the `TextInput` into a sliver (if even that). To compensate for that, you need to adjust the `height` as well.
2. When you do adjust `height`, you may run into [this double height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666795/textinput-typed-text-not-appearing-on-android). I don't know if that has since been fixed, but take a look at it if you are still seeing issues.
3. Lastly, `paddingHorizontal: 150` pushes it too far horizontally making nothing appear. Reduce that to something much smaller like `paddingHorizontal: 15`.