# TextInput not working in android react native

Tags: android, react-native

TextInput in android is not working when i click on the input and start typing, no text is shown as input. I tested it on android 8.1 and 7.1.

react-native-cli : 2.0.1
react-native : 0.55.4

```
class LoginForm extends Component{
    state={text: ''};
    render(){

        return(
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({text})}

                        style={{height: 20, width: 1.0}}
                    />
                </CardSection>
                <CardSection/>

                <CardSection>
                    <Button>Log In</Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide a minimal example so that others can reproduce your problem. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please mention `react-native` version also and if possible share some sample code.

Comment: Can you provide expo snack link?

Comment: @gus27 thanks for the advice i will remember it in future

Comment: @PrasunPal here is the code and the react-native version.

Comment: Is `TextField` a custom component or it is from any library?

Comment: Oops sorry its TextInput i updated it ..

Comment: In TextInput style `width: 1.0` is provided which cannot even show a character. Give a bigger value as width, for ex: `width: 20`.

Comment: Thankyou this worked for me adjusting the width to 200 and height to 40.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doubling the height of the text input style. I was having the same issue, and doubling the height to 40 fixed it for me. Seems to be an issue with android specifically.

[Where I found this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666795/textinput-typed-text-not-appearing-on-android)

Comment: This worked for me on Android, but doesn't feel like a solution, now the text input field is really tall, seems that we should be able to specify a smaller height for the TextInput and still see the text in the box that the user enters.

Answer (score 5):

We can give `padding: 0;`.
For me its working fine.

Comment: I tried doubling height and take care of darkmode but this paddgin: 0 what truly solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0' // remove this library and it works from build.gradle in app file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).